# Is it possible for me separate a pdf with pdfminer based on straight horizontal lines?

Tags: python, python-tesseract, pdfminer, tabula

I have a pdf with muliple tables where I haven't been successful with tabula for extracting its tables.

I noticed every table has a top straight horizontalline and a bottom horizontal line too, do I'd like to extract the separated content between each of these lines, so that later I can separate and organize it into the tables I'll use.

Is it possible to be done?

By the way: Tabula raises an error saying it can't read my document for 'utf-8', 'latin1' and 'ISO' can't read some character.

Comment: can you share that PDF or page at least?